# «52,6 процента» оценивается или оцениваются?

Tags: согласование

52,6 процента 
всходов озимых культур оценивается как «хорошее». Или оцениваются как «хорошие»?

Comment: Я бы сказал: оцениваЮтся как хорошИе. Почему? Ну, потому что всходы хорошие! Половина всходов – хорошие. И без кавычек.

Comment: я так понимаю, хорошие здесь – фраза из цитаты кого-то....

Comment: А что хотят сказать? Из того, что взошло, 52,6% хороших всходов (остальные всходы оцениваются  как не очень хорошие) или хорошо, что из посеянных семян 52,6 процента взошло?

Comment: из-за заморозков – часть, видимо, уцелела....

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, сказуемое здесь связано с количественно-именным сочетанием "пятьдесят два и шесть десятых" и нужно следовать правилам, изложенным Розенталем [[§184. Сказуемое при подлежащем – количественно-именном сочетании (счетном обороте)]](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm)

В нашем случае надо начать с того, что 52,6 процента всходов  - "хорошие". Только множественное число возможно здесь. А под влиянием того, что "хорошие" стоят во множественном числе, и сказуемое придется ставить во множественном числе

**52,6 процента всходов озимых культур оцениваются как «хорошие».**